# Minifying handlebars templates

Tags: html, handlebars.js, minify

I have the code like this:

```
<div class="my-super-class {{#if something}}{{else}}hidden{{/if}}">
```

Notice the space after 'my-super-class'

**Problem:**

If to minify this code snippet the space will be removed and we'll get `my-super-classhidden` class instead of `my-super-class hidden`.

How to resolve this issue without npm installations?

Comment: manually an option? http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/

Comment: @MatthewHarwood Your minifier doesn't minify files with handlebars properly. I can't do it manually cause I'm not the only developer so anyone  from my team can minify files and forget add spaces manually.

Comment: Ahh I miss understood your question. your order of tasks is incorrect.  You compile your handle bars then you minify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found something valuable. The only way for now is to install [this minifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier) and run it on node.js. It also can be well configured in many desired ways. It understands handlebars.js and minifies HTML better than other known minify services.

Answer (score 2):

You should run [`html-minifier`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier) from the command line, with the option

`--ignore-custom-fragments "/{{[{]?(.*?)[}]?}}/"`

This regex will ignore everything between `{{` and `}}` and minify the rest

**PS**: you can also add the space right before `hidden`

`<div class="my-super-class{{#if something}}{{else}} hidden{{/if}}">`